# How do I lubricate these spring loaded hinges?

Tags: hinges

Some of my cupboards have these spring loaded hinges, and they have started making an horrendous noise.

They look like this: [image]

How do I lubricate these hinges? Do I need to open them up? I'm afraid that if I open the wrong screw, putting them back together would be difficult.

Comment: You can try dry graphite lubricant on the hinges linking rods - remove the half moon cup from the door frame and you can get at them better. Make sure your adjustable locking  screw is not allowing movement.

Comment: Ken beat me to it.  You can get tubes of graphite lubricant with a long, thin tip, sometimes even like a hollow needle.  That lets you apply it in hard to reach places.

Comment: ...and it lasts longer than WD-40

Answer (score 1):

If dry graphite is problematic to apply you can also find it suspended in a liquid for use in locks. Lightweight oil or volatile lubricants flow into the lock leaving the suspended graphite behind when they evaporate. (Dry graphite, if you haven't had a reason to use it before, is also very easy to "shoot" by squeezing the tube. It's a *very* fine powder.)

A trip to the local hardware store will be a big help since you can see all of your options. "Zoom spout turbine oil" is probably not primarily used on turbines; I think people like the long, flexible tube.